# Using ng-if inside <li> in angular-js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use ng-if inside

based on a property value stored in my local system.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li ng-class="{ 'active': $state.current.name.indexOf('home') != -1 }">
            <a ui-sref="home">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ 'active': $state.current.name.indexOf('organization') != -1 }">
            <a ui-sref="organizations">Organizations</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="appConfig.flag" ng-class="{ 'active': $state.current.name.indexOf('ApplicationTemp') != -1 }">
            <a ui-sref="ApplicationTemp">Applications Temp</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Now, this flag is declared in my app.config.js as a flag as follows:

```
if (__LOCAL__) {
    appConfig.flag = true;
}
```

My Controller for the navbar is as follows:

```
import appConfig from './../../app.config';
export default function SideBarController() {
    'ngInject';
    var self = this;

    self.initialize = _initialize;
    self.initialize();

    //Private Functions
    function _initialize() {
        self.endpoints = appConfig.endpoints;
        self.isProd = appConfig.isProd;
    }

}
```

The word `LOCAL` basically is used for running the above system on my local system using npm scripts. 
The problem is, I can't use this in my sidebar and use it in my if condition properly. The result is, ApplicationTemp is always hidden when I apply this ng-if condition. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

It should be : `ng-if="appConfig.flag"`.

No need of string comparison.

**Update:**

You need to bind `appConfig.flag` to your controller, do it like :

```
function _initialize() {
        self.endpoints = appConfig.endpoints;
        self.isProd = appConfig.isProd;
        self.appConfig = {flag : appConfig.flag}; //add this too to use in html
    }
```

Comment: @sarah: is `appConfig` defined in your `controller $scope` ?, if not then add it there

Comment: @sarah: add `self.appConfig = { flag : appConfig.flag;}` in your `_initialize()` method, see updated answer

Comment: yep I reached here after hit and trial and it worked. Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

It must be `$scope` variable to use it in html template. Change variable in the condition to

```
$scope.appConfig.flag = true;
```

and then use as **anoop** said that is

```
ng-if="appConfig.flag"
```

Comment: what do you mean by template?

Comment: the HTML content you wrote above

Comment: I have edited my HTML content above to include your changes. But it doesn't work. If possible, can you have a look at the HTML content above to see if I have correctly included your changes?

Comment: No remove the first line

Comment: I have also added my sidebar.controller.js, do you mean I should add it there? If possible, can you edit my code and post it?

Comment: I think you are totally mixing angular1 and angular2. Which one you are using? 1 or 2?

Comment: I am using angular1. I added in controller and it worked. thanks for the help though.